# Working with an Access 2010 database from Java under Windows

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, ms-access-2010

Does anyone know how to access a Microsoft 2010 Access database from a Java program running on a Windows Vista OS?  An open source, or at least free solution would be preferred, but I will consider a commercial product if necessary.

I have tried a number of ways that I turned up by searching the web (all based on ODBC->JDBC), but none of them seem to work.

---

Murdoch, thanks for your answer.  My response was too big for a comment, so I'll add it here.

Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to set up the ODBC bridge on Vista running Microsoft Access 2010.  The "System DSN" tab of the ODBC Data Source Administrator only displays the SQL-Server driver when I click on the "Add..." button.

I'd like to set up a System DSN, but, if I have to, I might be able to do with a User DSN.  When I open the "User DSN" tab I see "MS Access Database" listed, but if I select it and click the "Configure..." button a message box pops up telling me that "The setup routines for the Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb) ODBC driver could not be found.  Please reinstall the driver."  I have tried a number of workarounds that I have found on the web, but none of them seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the JDBC ODBC Bridge driver, create an ODBC datasource and connect using JDBC something like this.

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:<data-source-name>");
```

EDIT:
  I should have also added, you can set up the ODBC data source in the control panel, goto Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Data Sourced (ODBC)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution.  If you are having a similar problem take a look at the following blog post on how to use ...

[Microsoft Access ODBC drivers for Vista x64](http://blogs.msmvps.com/spywaresucks/2007/05/10/microsoft-access-odbc-drivers-for-vista-x64/http://msmvps.com/blogs/spywaresucks/archive/2007/05/11/897398.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Now that the JDBC-ODBC Bridge has been removed from Java 8 a better approach would be to use the [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) JDBC driver. For more information see

[Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)